# How can I select 2 tables without overwriting each other?

Tags: php, sql, database, join

I have currently 2 tables in my database with the same columns.
The data inside is different, but I need to combine them into 1 table with a query.

I tried with joins but somehow I get that it overwrites the other one.

Comment: Where do you need the resulting data? Move all data from one into the other or all data in a 3rd table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do a join... you want to do a UNION

Let's say you created your first table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer  
(First_Name char(50),
Last_Name char(50),
Address char(50));
```

And your second table (with the same fields) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE customer2
(First_Name char(50),
Last_Name char(50),
Address char(50));
```

You want a UNION statement like this:

```
SELECT * from customer
UNION
SELECT * from customer2;
```

Of course, you could select specific fields rather than SELECT * if you just wanted that.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the data from both tables as if they were in one, try to use UNION:
`SELECT * FROM tab1

UNION

SELECT * FROM tab2`

Note: Only works if both tables have exactly the same columns. Otherwise you have to refine the SELECTs to match columns

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an alias for "duplicate" column when you use join. Something like

```
a.mycolumn as column, b.mycolumn as column2
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the "[SQL AS](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlas.php)".
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

With this solution, the tables don't need to be identic.

```
SELECT a.id AS id1, b.id AS id2 FROM table_1 a INNER JOIN table_2 b
```